# Yureka fastboot not detected in LINUX, but adb detects device

Tags: fastboot, micromax-yu-yureka

`fastboot` detects Redmi 2, but not Yureka.

I am trying to install Cyanogenmod in Yu Yureka. When I tried installing the CM zip with default recovery, it failed stating "Signature Verification Failed".

So I tried to install the TWRP recovery using fastboot. I did the following:

```
root@konoha:~# adb devices
List of devices attached 
2a25599 device

root@konoha:~# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c6:9039 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0bc2:5071 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

root@konoha:~# adb reboot bootloader

root@konoha:~# fastboot devices 

root@konoha:~# grep 05c6 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

root@konoha:~# cat /etc/group | grep plugdev
plugdev:x:46:itachi
root@konoha:~#
```

I get the fastboot screen on Yureka device, but no luck with `fastboot devices`.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Fastboot mode]

Some suggested that running fastboot as root user solved this. But that too didn't work for me. But for Redmi 2, I was successfully able to install TWRP recovery using fastboot, so that makes fastboot works, but not for Yureka.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Do you need to add udev usb rule for yureka?

Comment: @moonbutt74 I've already added the udev rules file from android website, and that contained the yureka's vendorid. Please see the pasted content. The `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c6:9039 Qualcomm, Inc.` is the Yureka device and the vendor id "05c6" is present in the rules file

Comment: Kenpachi, it may be that you are not in fastboot mode, meaning  ' adb reboot bootloder ' hasn't actually put you in fastboot mode. i don't know what model you actually have but follow the guide here concerning booting the device into fastboot mode then check your read again,
http://forum.xda-developers.com/yureka/orig-development/recovery-cwm-based-recovery-v6-0-5-1-t3001339

Comment: @moonbutt74 To unlock the bootloader, I must gain access to fastboot. BTW I get the Fastboot screen, but `fastboot devices` does not list the device

Comment: hmm okay take a look at this -- adb-fastboot-install
https://code.google.com/p/adb-fastboot-install/
Still not sure if it's the device or linux

Comment: In the recommended ways to boot the yureka into fastboot mode, abd reboot bootloader is not among them, Method 1 is enable developer options and enable advanced reboot options, plug in phone to pc and then select bootloader from the reboot menu, and Method B is outline in the XDA link. The only thing i can see is a duplicate group entry in your rules. Is that correct?

Comment: @moonbutt74 I tried that method as well. Held the Volume up button after connecting it to the PC, I get the same screen as when using `adb reboot bootloader`. Then tried using `fastboot devices`. No change there as well.

Comment: can you run chmod a+r  on 51-android.rules and then run fastboot again? all the information i can find is for windows, with one linux suggestion to update fastboot. Are your sure your vendor id is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yureka requires the vendor ID as a parameter for fastboot.
Try the following (tested on Yureka Plus):

```
% lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1ebf:7001  

% fastboot -i 0x1ebf devices
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this command for Yu Yureka

```
sudo fastboot -i 0x17ef devices
```