# Pixel 4a : adb detects device but fastboot command doesn't work

Tags: adb, rooting, fastboot, android-11, google-pixel-4a

*This is a self answered question that is different and may save hours of frustration to somebody*

**Related questions but none that helped**

- [ADB detects my device but fastboot doesn't](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194518/adb-detects-my-device-but-fastboot-doesnt)
- [Yureka fastboot not detected in LINUX, but adb detects device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119354/yureka-fastboot-not-detected-in-linux-but-adb-detects-device)
- [ADB detects but, fastboot does not detect device in windows 10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151692/adb-detects-but-fastboot-does-not-detect-device-in-windows-10)
- [adb can find device but fastboot cannot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53522/adb-can-find-device-but-fastboot-cannot)
- [fastboot not showing device (nokia 2.1 ) but adb works fine](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225490/fastboot-not-showing-device-nokia-2-1-but-adb-works-fine)
- [adb devices show phone in debug mod but not in fastboot mod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/adb-devices-show-phone-in-debug-mod-but-not-in-fastboot-mod)
- [Fastboot detects phone in the fastboot mode but not when phone is on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223443/fastboot-detects-phone-in-the-fastboot-mode-but-not-when-phone-is-on)

**My situation**

- After more than 6 months I thought of updating security patches on my Pixel 4a Android 11 (stock)  and root it again.
- I uninstalled Magisk , applied OTA update , extracted boot image and patched it with magisk ([see this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232257/how-do-you-root-a-device-with-magisk-when-it-doesnt-have-a-custom-recovery)). All smooth

**Problem**

I needed to run `fastboot flash boot patched.img` to root the device. But when I run the command response is `<waiting for any device>`, which was strange since `adb devices` shows device serial.

**Things tried, without any luck**

- Updated adb on Lint Minux, it was latest
- Switched to Windows 10 and updated
- Andrew in chat pointed to an XDA thread, which was better covered by Izzy here [How do I get my device detected by ADB on Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux/144967#144967). Added udev rule but then no dice.
- Firelord in chat suggested it could be `plugdev` issue so tried the solution mentioned in this Stack Overflow question [adb devices => no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53887322), though the problem wasn't similar
- Multiple cables , rebooting Android, Windows, Linux when I was at a loss to figure out
- Variations of fastboot like `fastboot flash boot_a patched.img`, `fastboot flash boot --slot all patched.img` and `sudo fastboot devices`

Finally, the solution ....

Answer (score 1):

I have now idea why this worked. Before running fastboot commands rebooted device in download mode:

- `adb reboot bootloader` to get into fastboot
- `fastboot devices` shows device serial
- `fastboot flash boot patched.img` works :)
- `fastboot reboot` to get back to normal device state
- Device is rooted and I see `su` permission requests

Note: Some [devices of LG](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225490/fastboot-not-showing-device-nokia-2-1-but-adb-works-fine#comment293710_225490) and Samsung lack fastboot functionality.